# Implementation of delegates for flight operations

Tags: c#, delegates

I borrowed the code from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19405571/failed-to-understand-the-use-of-delegates-in-real-world-scenarios). I'm trying to implement the delegate in that code. Below is my outcome so far.

What else can be done to improve this code? Any suggestions?  I would appreciate suggestions regarding delegate, code reuse, etc.

```
class Program
{        
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var flights = new List<Flight>
        {
            new Flight {Number = "FL001", DepartureTime = DateTime.Now},
            new Flight {Number = "FL002", DepartureTime = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1)},
            new Flight {Number = "FL003", ArrivalTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30)},
            new Flight {Number = "FL004", ArrivalTime = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1.30)},
        };

        var tower = new FlightTower(flights);

        // Flight 003 asking for landing
        var flightAskingForLanding= flights.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Number == "FL003");

        if (flightAskingForLanding != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Flight {0} \t: Okay to land?", flightAskingForLanding.Number));
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Flight Tower \t: {0}", tower.CanLand(flightAskingForLanding)));
        }

        Func<Flight, bool> checkSchedule = x => flightAskingForLanding.ArrivalTime.IsConflictWithFlightTime(x.ArrivalTime) && flightAskingForLanding.Number != x.Number;
        checkSchedule += x => flightAskingForLanding.ArrivalTime.IsConflictWithFlightTime(x.DepartureTime) && flightAskingForLanding.Number != x.Number;

        if (flightAskingForLanding != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Flight {0} \t: Okay to land?", flightAskingForLanding.Number));
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Flight Tower \t: {0}", tower.CheckRunwayStatus(flightAskingForLanding,
                                                                                            checkSchedule,
                                                                                            x => x.ArrivalTime == flights.Min(f => f.ArrivalTime))));
        }       

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

}


public class FlightTower
{
    private readonly List<Flight> _schedule;

    public FlightTower(List<Flight> schedule)
    {
        _schedule = schedule;
    }

    //this method is to show my initial implementation
    public bool CanTakeOff(Flight flight)
    {
        //todo: add code to check for both arrival time and departure time as in the CanLand method
        var arrivingFlights = _schedule.Where(x => x.ArrivalTime == DateTime.Now);

        if (arrivingFlights.ToList().Count == 0)
        {
            var flightInQueue = _schedule.FirstOrDefault(x => x.DepartureTime == _schedule.Min(c => c.DepartureTime));
            if (flightInQueue != null && flightInQueue.Number == flight.Number)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    //this method is to show my initial implementation
    public bool CanLand(Flight flight)
    {
        var arrvingFlight = _schedule.Where(x => flight.ArrivalTime.IsConflictWithFlightTime(x.ArrivalTime) && flight.Number != x.Number);
        var depatingFlight = _schedule.Where(x => flight.ArrivalTime.IsConflictWithFlightTime(x.DepartureTime) && flight.Number != x.Number);
        if (arrvingFlight.ToList().Count == 0 && depatingFlight.ToList().Count == 0)
        {                
            var flightInQueue = _schedule.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ArrivalTime == _schedule.Min(c => c.ArrivalTime));
            if (flightInQueue != null && flightInQueue.Number == flight.Number)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    //this will replace above CanLand and CanTakeOff methods
    public bool CheckRunwayStatus(Flight flight, Func<Flight, bool> checkSchedule, Func<Flight, bool> checkFlightQueue)
    {        
        var flightStatus = _schedule.Where(checkSchedule);
        if (flightStatus.ToList().Count == 0 )
        {
            var flightInQueue = _schedule.FirstOrDefault(checkFlightQueue);
            if (flightInQueue != null && flightInQueue.Number == flight.Number)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

public class Flight
{
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public DateTime DepartureTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime ArrivalTime { get; set; }
    public int TotalCrew { get; set; }       
}


public static class DateTimeExtension
{
    public static bool IsConflictWithFlightTime(this DateTime currentFlightTime, DateTime nextFlightTime)
    {
        TimeSpan timeDiff= nextFlightTime - currentFlightTime;
        double totalMinutes = timeDiff.TotalMinutes;
        if (totalMinutes < 0)
            totalMinutes = totalMinutes * -1;

        totalMinutes = Math.Round(totalMinutes);
        if (totalMinutes <= 30.0D)
            return true;
        else
            return false;

    }
}
```

Here's my implementation of `ConductFlightOperations`. I'm not sure if this is proper way of doing it.

```
public void ConductFlightOperations()
    {
        // Flight 003 asking for landing
        var flightAskingForLanding = _schedule.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Number == "FL003");

        if (flightAskingForLanding != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Flight {0} \t: Okay to land?", flightAskingForLanding.Number));
            LandingClearance(flightAskingForLanding);
            flightAskingForLanding.Land();
        }          

    }
```

Here's my implementation of `Deconflict`. Right now it only check for `someFlight.ArrivalTime` (which is for Landing flights), what should be proper way to reuse same code to check for `someFlight.DepartureTime`(for Departing flights)? Should I pass some flag or create new method or something else?

```
    protected bool Deconflict(Flight someFlight)
    {
        if (_schedule.Any(x => x.Number != someFlight.Number &&  Math.Abs((x.ArrivalTime - someFlight.ArrivalTime).TotalMinutes) < 20D))
            return false;

        if (_schedule.Any(x => x.Number != someFlight.Number && Math.Abs((x.DepartureTime - someFlight.ArrivalTime).TotalMinutes) < 20D))
            return false;

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks all for their time and efforts. @radarbob most of the pieces are clear now. Please advice for the EDIT in my questions.

Comment: @radarbob could you please spend few minutes from your valuable time to give answer on my EDIT part?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Be more Object Oriented

Most of the code in `Main()` should be in the `Flight` or `FlightTower` classes. Seems to me that if it's in an appropriate class then its re-usable.

#### What does a Tower *DO*?

- Clear flights to land (i.e. process a landing request)
- Clear flights to takeoff
- Deconflict in/out bound traffic

#### What does a Flight *DO*?

- Actually lands
- Actually takes off

```
public class FlightTower {
    // I dont know what if anything to return just yet
    public xxx LandingClearance(Flight incomingFlight) {}
    public xxx TakeoffClearance(Flight outgoingFlight) {}
}

public class Flight {
    public xxx Takeoff() {}
    public xxx Land() {}
}
```

#### Making up an excuse to use delegates

Flight just "does what it's told" - i.e. whatever method the `delegate` holds. Takeoff/landing requests gives context as to what kind of instructions we're talking about.

```
public delegate void FlightInstructions()

public class Tower {
    public void LandingInstructions() {}
    public void HoldingInstructions() {}
    public void TakeoffInstructions() {}
    public void HoldForTakeoffInstructions() {}

    public xxx LandingClearance(Flight incomingFlight) {
        If (Deconflict(incomingFlight)) {
            incomingFlight.Instructions = LandingInstructions;
        else
            incomingFlight.Instructions = HoldingInstructions;
        }
    }

    protected bool Deconflict(Flight someFlight) {}
}

public class Flight {
    public FlightInstructions Instructions;

    public xxx Takeoff() { Instructions(); }
    public xxx Land() { Instructions(); }
}
```

#### An abstract `Main()` is a good thing

```
public static void Main() {
    FlightTower tower = new FlightTower(BuildFlightSchedule());

   tower.ConductFlightOperations(); // iterates the _schedule - all that junk exposed in the original Main()
}

public static List<Flight> BuildFlightSchedule() {}
```

#### Miscellaneous

This:

```
double totalMinutes = timeDiff.TotalMinutes;
if (totalMinutes < 0)
    totalMinutes = totalMinutes * -1;
```

Could be this:

```
double totalMinutes = Math.Abs(timeDiff.TotalMinutes);
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @radarbobs answer, a few more technical points about your code (mainly related to your usage of Linq):

1. `flightAskingForLanding` is obtained using `FirstOrDefault`, yet your code will crash when building `checkSchedule` as you unconditionally access the variable.
2. In `FlightTower.CanTakeOff()`, you do this:

   ```
   var arrivingFlights = _schedule.Where(x => x.ArrivalTime == DateTime.Now);

   if (arrivingFlights.ToList().Count == 0)
   {
       ...
   }
   ```

   - It's not necessary to create a list to get the count, the Linq extensions define a `Count()` extension method on `IEnumerable<T>`.
   - Furthermore there is an [overload for `Count()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which accepts a predicate so you can shorten this to: `if (_schedule.Count(x => x.ArrivalTime == DateTime.Now) == 0)`
   - But actually you are not really interested in the count. What you want is "check if there aren't any flight arriving now" so you should use [`Any()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (which can break early if the sequence is not empty): `if (!_schedule.Any(x => x.ArrivalTime == DateTime.Now))`
3. This `_schedule.FirstOrDefault(x => x.DepartureTime == _schedule.Min(c => c.DepartureTime))` is an O(N<sup>2</sup>) operation (for every item in schedule find the minimum in schedule and compare). Unfortunately there is no nice "return object where a certain property has the minimum" built into Linq but there are [some alternative options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/914109/how-to-use-linq-to-select-object-with-minimum-or-maximum-property-value) (worst case: first find the minimum and store in a local variable and then search the object)
4. Above two points also apply to `CanLand()` and `CheckRunwayStatus`.